# Algorithm to sort hues into shortest span, e.g. `350,354,2,10,15`? [0-360 deg]

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, hsv

In color schemes, I would like to sort the hues, but would like to avoid 'big gaps', i.e. prefer `350,354,2,10,15` over `2,10,15,350,354` (when expressed as 0-360 degree values). What's the best approach of doing that (eg in php)? Is it finding the 'biggest gap' and start after that? Any better ideas?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? What would be better than finding the 'biggest gap' and start after that? A faster solution? One with smaller gaps? More elegant code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that many:

1. just sort in order
2. find the variance (modulo 360)   (i.e, how far out are they from the 'modulo 360 mean')
3. Move the first to the end, check variance again.
4. After you have tried all of them, choose the one with the smallest.

This algorithm is O(N^2) in the size of the of the list.

The main takeaway is that you only have N 'rotations' here.  Decide a 'gappiness' statistic, and brute force it over all N rotations, and use the arrangement that minimizes the 'gappiness'.

Comment: sorry if im being pedantic, but the sort is still O(n*logn) so the efficiency of the algorithm as a whole is at least O(n*logn).  Also, isnt finding the variance just once an O(N) operation?  If so, finding a variance N times is quadratic unless there is a faster way to find the variance subsequent times

Comment: You are completely correct, and I have corrected the answer.  Good catch, and looking back on it, I hope that it was just a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Just find the  biggest gap and put it in the beginning.

1. Sort the array
2. Find biggest gap (loop through the array, find the biggest distance between two neighbors)
3. Move the gap to be the beginning (Another loop to shift all the numbers)

Comment: How is this different from ajo's solution "finding the 'biggest gap' and start after that"?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand him correctly. he said you should find a mean, calculate the distance from it, move them one by one till you get there. Which is not what I'm saying.

Comment: ??? I mean, the solution in the question says: find the biggest gap, start after that (== move the gap to the beginning). So, your answer is the same as the question.?

Comment: This doesn't minimize the global "gappiness" very well.